# how to assign linq result to multidimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

i want to assign the linq result to a multidimensional array and the below is my code, can any one tell me what i am doing wrong.

```
var query = (from b in db.FourBodyImages
             where b.Status == true
             orderby b.CreaedDate descending
             select new { b.BodyImage, b.Description, b.HeaderName }
           ).Take(4).ToArray();

if(query.Count()>0)
{
    string[,,] x = new string[4, 4,4];
    x[,,] = query;

    for (int i = 0; i < query.Length; i++)
    {

        if (i == 0)
        { 
            imgBody1.ImageUrl = "FourBodyImages/" + x[0,0,0].ToString();
        }
        if (i == 1)
        {
            imgBody2.ImageUrl = "FourBodyImages/" + x[1,1,1].ToString();
        }
        if (i == 2)
        {
            imgBody3.ImageUrl = "FourBodyImages/" + x[2,2,2].ToString();
        }
        if (i == 3)
        {
            imgBody4.ImageUrl = "FourBodyImages/" + x[3,3,3].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think multidimensional array means what you think it means. :) Why do you need it to be multidimensional? A simple array of anonymous objects could do just fine.

Comment: An array `x[4,4,4]` has 64 elements, not 4 elements. Are you sure that you need a 3D array?

Comment: no i dont need a 3d array, let me correct my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to get 4 objects from the database, and then use them to fill 4 images, all you need to do is:

```
//this generates an array of (up to 4) objects of an anonymous type
var query = (from b in db.FourBodyImages
                     where b.Status == true
                     orderby b.CreaedDate descending
                     select new { b.BodyImage, b.Description, b.HeaderName }
                   ).Take(4).ToArray();

//no need for count, we can use the array's length
if (query.Length < 4)
{
   //i have no idea about your requirements, 
   //but if we have less than 4 images - panic
   throw new InvalidOperationException()
}

//no need for the "for-if", that's an anti-patern
imgBody1.ImageUrl = "FourBodyImages/" + query[0].BodyImage;
imgBody2.ImageUrl = "FourBodyImages/" + query[1].BodyImage;
imgBody3.ImageUrl = "FourBodyImages/" + query[2].BodyImage;
imgBody4.ImageUrl = "FourBodyImages/" + query[3].BodyImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you want a three-dimensional array to start with. You're only taking 4 values... why is that not just a *one-dimensional* array?

```
var query = (from b in db.FourBodyImages
             where b.Status == true
             orderby b.CreaedDate descending
             select new { b.BodyImage, b.Description, b.HeaderName }
             ).Take(4).ToArray();

var bodies = new[] { imgBody1, imgBody2, imgBody3, imgBody4 };
for (int i = 0; i < query.Length; i++)
{
    // Or whichever property you're interested in...
    bodies[i].ImageUrl = "FourBodyImages/" + query[i].BodyImage;
}
```

If this doesn't help, please give us more idea of what you're actually trying to achieve. Why does your query return three properties, for example, and how do you want to use them?

Comment: what about b.description and b.headername if they are to be assigned to different labels

Comment: @Tan: Well it's hard to give sample code without any clue of what you're trying to do. If you could clarify what you're trying to achieve, we may be able to help more. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: my query result return four rows of data which i want to assign to 4 different labels,images

Comment: @Tan: You're not being clear - what does "4 different labels,images" mean *exactly*?